# Add Navigation Bar to TabBar Swift iOS9

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have one TabBar with 4 icons, one icon (number4) is a Photo Gallery with 3 buttons/images that show 10 images in ViewController (number5). I need a Back button from (number 5) to come back to (number4).
Problem is when I click Back from (5) for come back to (4) the TabBar in (4) disappear. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Post a screenshot of your storyboard so we can better understand your view hierarchy. Post a link to your picture, someone will put it inside the post

Comment: Hi thanks  ;) 

http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rwmflv&s=8#.VgMEMbSKDrA
http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j0lkbm&s=8#.VgMEhLSKDrA

Comment: I've inserted in your post, accept my edit

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your view controller number 4 (from now on VC4) is the root view controller of one tab of the TabBar and has a show segue to VC5.

The best way to display automatically the back button and keep the bottom bar I could think of is to embed VC4 in a navigation controller thus having:

> TabBar Item -> UINavigationController -> VC4 (as root of the navigation controller) -> VC5 (reached through segue)

Before doing so I would suggest to remove the navigation bar you manually added in VC5.

If this doesn't work make sure that the properties of the navigation controller in Attribute Inspector highlighted in picture are not checked as the first will display a toolbar that hides the TabBar and the second will hide the TabBar when going to VC5.

[image: Don't show toolbar]
[image: Don't hide bottom bar on push]

Comment: Grazie mille Marco!
This works, but in the VC4 I want to hide the navigation bar. The problem is that if I hide the bar in the VC4 is also hidden in the VC5.
I try to hide it by code but does´t work very well.
I we'll see better tomorrow.
Saluti

Comment: Set the navigation bar of the navigation controller to be hidden by default then when you are pushing a view controller show it (you can use prepareForSegue in VC4), then when VC4 becames visible again hide it

Comment: Ok, I was also seeing that the "friend" Segue had much to do in this story!
Thanks Marco